# When I use history.push() my component don't render, I need to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom to make my routes.

I have a file called `AppRouter.js` that have my routes:

```
const AppRouter = props => {

    const loading = useSelector(state => state.loadingStates)
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/login",
                            }}
                        />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/registrar" component={LoginWrapper} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginWrapper} />
                </div>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default AppRouter
```

My index.js render this file router:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <AppRouter/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So, when i go to `localhost:3333` i'm redirected by the login page.
In the login page, after the user make the login, i do a `history.push('/home')`:

```
function* makeLogin(action) {
    yield put(allActions.loadingActions.startLoading());
    try {    
        const { data } = yield call(api.post, '/login', action.payload);
        yield put(allActions.loginActions.setUser(data))
        yield put(allActions.loadingActions.endLoading());
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data))
        history.push('/home')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

the link in my browser update to `localhost:3333/home` but my component still shows the login page, i need to reload to the component render.

My **history.js** that is imported by the file saga.js that make the makeLogin request:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Why this is happening? how i fix this?

Comment: Where is history defined?

Comment: @Shmli Breuer please check my update, i write about this. The history is defined in a file called history.js that is imported by the class that make the makeLogin()

Comment: That's not how React Router works. You need to conditionally render a `<Redirect />` after a successful login (which can be triggered by changing the loggedIn state). You will probably want to wrap all of your authorized routes in a HOC like this: https://github.com/indiana-department-of-transportation/tmc-router/blob/master/packages/authonly/src/authonly.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your custom history to your router

```
**** see change ****
import history from "../path to your history.js file";

const AppRouter = props => {

const loading = useSelector(state => state.loadingStates)
return (

    **** see change ****
    <Router history={history }>
        <Switch>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                        }}
                    />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/registrar" component={LoginWrapper} />
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginWrapper} />
            </div>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
}

export default AppRouter
```

See this page [for reference](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)